# Double integral in RcppNumerical

Tags: r, rcpp, numerical-integration

I have to calculate the double integral of the function:

```
 > DIntegral <- function(x,y){res <- pnorm(x,1,0.1) * dexp(y-2,1.2)
                              return(res)
                              }
```

The upper limit for x and y are: `10` and `Infinity` respectively.
The lower limit for x and y are:  `1` and `2` respectively.

How can I do this double integration in `RcppNumerical`?

For one dimensional integration my C++ file looks like:

```
    // [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
   // [[Rcpp::depends(RcppNumerical)]]
   #include <RcppNumerical.h>
   using namespace Numer;



class PDF: public Func
 {
 private:

  double beta;
  double M0;

public:
  PDF( double beta_, double M0_): beta(beta_), M0(M0_) {};

  double operator()(const double& x) const
  { 
    return  R::dexp(x-M0,beta,0);

  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double integrate_test2( double beta, double M0, double upper, double      lower)
{

  PDF f( beta, M0);
  double err_est;
  int err_code;
  double res = integrate ( f, lower, upper,err_est,err_code);
  return(res);

}
```

**Code for 2 dimensional integration with finite limits**

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
 // [[Rcpp::depends(RcppNumerical)]]
#include <RcppNumerical.h>
using namespace Numer;



class PDF: public MFunc
{
private:
  double mu;
  double sigma;
  double beta;
  double M0;

 public:
  PDF( double mu_, double sigma_, double beta_, double M0_): mu(mu_),     sigma(sigma_), beta(beta_), M0(M0_) {};

  double operator()(Constvec& x)
  { 
    return  R::pnorm(x[0],mu,sigma,1,0) * R::dexp(x[1]-M0,beta,0);

  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double integrate_test2( double mu, double sigma, double beta, double M0)
{
  Eigen::VectorXd lower(2);
  lower << 1, 2;
  Eigen::VectorXd upper(2);
  upper << 10, 50;

  PDF f( mu, sigma, beta, M0);
  double err_est;
  int err_code;
  double err_est2;
  int err_code2;
  double res = integrate ( f, lower, upper,err_est,err_code);
  return(res);

}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why does it have to be `RcppNumerical`?

Comment: Because the example I showed is much simpler than what I am using actually. And I have to apply it for large datasets which makes it very slow.

Comment: @RalfStubner look at my C++ code for one dimensional integration

Comment: The [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppNumerical/vignettes/introduction.html#multi-dimensional) has an example for 2D integration. Did you try to adapt that?

Comment: @RalfStubner yes, I am trying to follow that entirely. do you know how to put "infinity" as upper limit in Rcpp?

Comment: Have you tried `std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()` or `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`? And if you are following that documentation, it would be better to post the 2D code you tried so far. Maybe it already works for finite arguments?

Comment: @RalfStubner yes, it works for finite arguments. I am posting that code as well

Comment: @RalfStubner using std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity() or std::numeric_limits<double>::max() gives me NaN value

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your code to take the integration limits as arguments and to return the error code and estimate:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppNumerical)]]
#include <RcppNumerical.h>
using namespace Numer;

class PDF: public MFunc
{
private:
  double mu;
  double sigma;
  double beta;
  double M0;

public:
  PDF( double mu_, double sigma_, double beta_, double M0_): mu(mu_),     sigma(sigma_), beta(beta_), M0(M0_) {};

  double operator()(Constvec& x)
  { 
    return  R::pnorm(x[0],mu,sigma,1,0) * R::dexp(x[1]-M0,beta,0);

  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List integrate_test2( double mu, double sigma, double beta, double M0, Eigen::VectorXd lower, Eigen::VectorXd upper)
{
  PDF f( mu, sigma, beta, M0);
  double err_est;
  int err_code;
  double res = integrate ( f, lower, upper,err_est,err_code);
  return Rcpp::List::create(
    Rcpp::Named("result") = res,
    Rcpp::Named("error_estimate") = err_est,
    Rcpp::Named("error_code") = err_code
  );
}
/*** R
integrate_test2(1, 0.1, 1.2, 2, c(1, 2), c(10, 50))
integrate_test2(1, 0.1, 1.2, 2, c(1, 2), c(10, 1e4))
integrate_test2(1, 0.1, 1.2, 2, c(1, 2), c(10, 1e6))
integrate_test2(1, 0.1, 1.2, 2, c(1, 2), c(10, 1e8))
*/
```

Result:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('2d_int.cpp')

> integrate_test2(1, 0.1, 1.2, 2, c(1, 2), c(10, 50))
$result
[1] 8.950068

$error_estimate
[1] 0.3570577

$error_code
[1] 1


> integrate_test2(1, 0.1, 1.2, 2, c(1, 2), c(10, 1e4))
$result
[1] 4.787999

$error_estimate
[1] 16.12484

$error_code
[1] 1


> integrate_test2(1, 0.1, 1.2, 2, c(1, 2), c(10, 1e6))
$result
[1] 1.605216e-314

$error_estimate
[1] 4.320299e-313

$error_code
[1] 0


> integrate_test2(1, 0.1, 1.2, 2, c(1, 2), c(10, 1e8))
$result
[1] 0

$error_estimate
[1] 0

$error_code
[1] 0
```

So for small values the upper limit of y, the integration does not converge. And when it does converge, the result is (nearly) zero. This does not change when one increases the upper limit up to about `1e307`, i.e. almost `.Machine$double.xmax`. After that I get `NaN`.

However, if I use the `cubature` package the result is quite different:

```
library(cubature)
DIntegral <- function(x){
  res <- pnorm(x[1],1,0.1) * dexp(x[2]-2,1.2)
  return(res)
}
cubintegrate(f = DIntegral, lower = c(1, 2), upper = c(10, 50), method = "hcubature")
#> $integral
#> [1] 8.961023
#> 
#> $error
#> [1] 4.888071e-05
#> 
#> $neval
#> [1] 983
#> 
#> $returnCode
#> [1] 0
cubintegrate(f = DIntegral, lower = c(1, 2), upper = c(10, 1000), method = "hcubature")
#> $integral
#> [1] 8.960415
#> 
#> $error
#> [1] 7.145898e-05
#> 
#> $neval
#> [1] 1701611595
#> 
#> $returnCode
#> [1] 0
cubintegrate(f = DIntegral, lower = c(1, 2), upper = c(10, Inf), method = "hcubature")
#> $integral
#> [1] 8.960105
#> 
#> $error
#> [1] 8.515124e-05
#> 
#> $neval
#> [1] 1706522167
#> 
#> $returnCode
#> [1] 0
```

I am not sure what is going on here.

Comment: I am also not sure what's wrong here. Is it possible to integrate without defining a functor?